# How to create a pop up message button with a value using tkinter in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create a pop up message in Python that I can create my own button names and set them to a value any suggestions how? 
Ex: Yes= 1, No = 2, Stores Only = 3

```
     msg = 'There was a problem  data.'
     tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error!",msg)
```

This all I have now any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `SimpleDialog` class in `tkinter.simpledialog` module can be used in your case:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.simpledialog import SimpleDialog

root = tk.Tk()

def show_message():
    dlg = SimpleDialog(root, title='Error!', text='There was a problem data!',
                       buttons=['Yes', 'No', 'Stores Only'])
    answer = dlg.go()
    # answer = 0 for yes, 1 for No and 2 for 'Stores Only'
    # i.e answer is the index of the button in buttons
    print(answer)

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Show Message', command=show_message)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there a way I don't get the first pop up message ? I don't need the show message button.